# Do the even cycles of a graph form a subspace of the cycle space?

Tags: graph-theory, eulerian-path

From Wikipedia:

> The [cylce space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_space) of an undirected graph is the set of its [Eulerian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_graph) subgraphs. This set of subgraphs can be described algebraically as a vector space over the two-element finite field.

The vector addition operation is the [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference).

---

My main question is if the number of *independent* even cycles in a graph is well-defined or if it is dependent on the choice of cycles.

It occurred to me that if the subset of even cycles is closed under vector addition, then it would form a subspace of the cycle space and the number of independent even cycles is the unique value that is the dimension of that subspace.

---

I've found a reference ([Theorem 2.2.9](https://books.google.com/books?id=FA8SObZcbs4C&lpg=PA30&pg=PA31)) that states

> The multiplicity of the eigenvalue ${}-2$ in the line graph $L(H)$ is equal to the maximal number of independent even cycles in $H$.

Is this maximal number just the dimension of the basis or is such a basis not even well-defined.

Comment: I'm confused about the reference since \bar{E}(H) is over GF(2) which I assume is mod 2 what does eigenvalue -2 even mean???
The other part is they translate even cycles as some edges have 1 some -1 does that not change definition of cycle space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathscr{C}_0(G)=\{E\in\mathscr{C}(G):|E|\text{ is even}\}$. Let $E_0,E_1\in\mathscr{C}_0(G)$, with $|E_0|=2m$ and $|E_1|=2n$. If $k=|E_0\cap E_1|$, then

$$|E_0\mathbin{\triangle}E_1|=|E_0\setminus E_1|+|E_1\setminus E_0|=(2m-k)+(2n-k)=2(m+n-k)\;,$$

so $E_0\mathbin{\triangle}E_1\in\mathscr{C}_0(G)$, and $\mathscr{C}_0(G)$ is indeed a subspace of $\mathscr{C}(G)$.

Comment: M Scott  can you explain the   multiplicity of the eigenvalue −2 in the line graph L(H) is equal to the maximal number of independent even cycles in H  part? 
my understanding is that the cycle space is over mod 2 so what does eigenvalue of -2 even mean?